# How to get sizes of visible area in Sencha Touch 2 application

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to show DIV element on Panel with height equal to half size of visible area of the panel. There is no problem with resize. But how can I get sizes of visible area of the panel (without titlebars & toolbars)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found only one way to do that.
You can find element with class `x-scroll-container` in current view. Sizes of this element will be the sizes of visible area.